# Como acessar os atributos personalizados de uma propriedade usando VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, propriedade, atributos

Eu tenho uma solução em VB.NET onde estou implementando alguns *custom attributes*. Um deles é para as propriedades, exemplo:

```vb
Namespace Attributes
  <AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>
  Public Class DescriptionAttribute : Inherits Attribute

    Sub New(Name As String)
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String

  End Class
End Namespace
```

Eu preciso acessar o `Name` desses atributos vindos das classes, então eu criei uma função de extensão para a `PropertyInfo`, assim:

```vb
<Extension()>
Function GetDescription(Prop As PropertyInfo) As String
  Dim attr As DescriptionAttribute = Prop.GetCustomAttribute(GetType(DescriptionAttribute))
  If (attr IsNot Nothing) Then Return attr.Name
  Return Prop.Name
End Function
```

E quero poder usar essa função em qualquer lugar, como por exemplo em um `Override` do método `ToString`:

```vb
Public Class Foo

  <Description("Hello world with espace")>
  Public Property HelloWorld As String

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String

    return $"{HelloWorld.GetDescription()} - {HelloWorld}";

  End Function

End Class
```

O problema é que não sei como fazer para acessar esse atributo vindo da propriedade. A única forma que consegui seria se eu fizesse uma busca em uma instância da classe, mas não entendo que seja a melhor forma de se fazer no VB.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível usar o método de extensão assim diretamente como você tentou, porque o método se aplica somente a tipos `PropertyInfo`, e a propriedade `HelloWorld` é do tipo `String`, por isso é necessário primeiro obter o `PropertyInfo` dessa propriedade.

Eu fiz uma pesquisa e vi que você pode fazer isso de forma "manual", pegando o tipo da classe e depois usando o método `GetProperty()`. Você pode fazer isso usando o nome da propriedade, como um `String`:

```
Dim propInfoManual As PropertyInfo = GetType(Foo).GetProperty("HelloWorld")
```

Ou você pode usar o operador `NameOf`, que evita erros de digitação, que serão notados já em momento de compilação:

```
Dim propInfoManual As PropertyInfo = GetType(Foo).GetProperty(NameOf(Foo.HelloWorld))
```

Mas, se você ainda quiser fazer um método de extensão, você pode fazer assim, se for passar o nome da propriedade como um `String`:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetPropInfo(Of T)(origem As T, prop As String) As PropertyInfo

   Return GetType(T).GetProperty(prop)

End Function
```

Se quiser aquela vantagem da tipagem forte, que possibilita pegar erros de digitação em momento de compilação, nesse caso a coisa fica mais complicada e a única forma que achei foi usando as classes de construção/desconstrução de expressões *lambda*:

```
' Necessário para usar as classes de expressões lambda.
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

'[...]

<Extension()>
Public Function GetPropInfo(Of TSource, TProp)(origem As TSource,
                                               seletorProp As Expression(Of Func(Of TProp))
                                              ) As PropertyInfo

   Select Case seletorProp.Body.NodeType
      Case ExpressionType.MemberAccess
         Dim memExp As MemberExpression = DirectCast(seletorProp.Body, MemberExpression)
         Return DirectCast(memExp.Member, PropertyInfo)
      Case Else
         Throw New ArgumentException()
   End Select

End Function
```

Para testar os três métodos:

```
Public Class Foo

   <Description("Hello world with space")>
   Public Property HelloWorld As String

   Public Function DescricaoPropriedade() As String

      Dim descManual As String = GetType(Foo).GetProperty(NameOf(Foo.HelloWorld)).GetDescription()
      Dim descExtStr As String = Me.GetPropInfo("HelloWorld").GetDescription()
      Dim descExtLambda As String = Me.GetPropInfo(Function() Me.HelloWorld).GetDescription()

      Return $"Desc manual: {descManual} {vbCrLf}" &
             $"Desc estendido (str): {descExtStr} {vbCrLf}" &
             $"Desc estendido (lambda): {descExtLambda}"

   End Function

End Class
```

Você também pode usar o método de extensão com *lambda* sem os `Me.`, eu coloquei só para ficar mais didático.

Fontes:

> - [c# - How to get the PropertyInfo of a specific property? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491429/8133067)
> - [.net - VB.NET function get property name as string - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036760/8133067)
> - [c# - Retrieving Property name from lambda expression - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/672212/8133067)
> - [c# - Extension method to get property name - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32378113/8133067)
> - [Extension Methods (Visual Basic) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods)
> - [Generic Procedures in Visual Basic | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-procedures)

**EDIÇÃO**

Na hora não visualizei, mas agora percebi que é possível usar a solução mais simples de extensão, com parâmetro `String` ao invés de expressão *lambda*, e ainda ter tipagem forte, usando aqui também o operador `NameOf`:

```
Dim descExtStr As String = Me.GetPropInfo(NameOf(HelloWorld)).GetDescription()
```